# GroupBy Condition and Date to make seperate columns-Python

Tags: python, date, conditional-statements

I am trying to group data on date and based on condition of the direction column.
The df looks like :

```
    date      value     direction
0   2000-01-01  180     SE
1   2000-01-02  200     SW
2   2000-01-03  340     NW
3   2000-01-04  340     NW
4   2000-01-05  200     SW
```

This is what I have so far but there has got to be an easier way:

```
df[df['direction'].astype(str)=='SE'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M", key="date")).count()
df[df['direction'].astype(str)=='NE'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M", key="date")).count()
df[df['direction'].astype(str)=='SW'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M", key="date")).count()
df[df['direction'].astype(str)=='NW'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M", key="date")).count()
```

The result for each separate direction:

```
         value  direction
date        
2000-01-31  7   7
2000-02-29  6   6
2000-03-31  7   7
2000-04-30  6   6
2000-05-31  3   3
```

The code above will filter based on ['direction'] but if the direction is not present in that month it can throw an error when I merge the data.

I am looking for an output:

```
            NE  SW etc.
date        
2000-01-31  7   7
2000-02-29  6   6
2000-03-31  7   7
2000-04-30  6   6
2000-05-31  3   3
```

Comment: What happened to the value column, in your desired output? Is it just discarded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df.groupby('date').apply(lambda gdf: gdf['direction'].value_counts()).unstack().fillna(0.0)
```